# What's the easiest way to separate two populations in a scatterplot?

Tags: r, classification, clustering, threshold

I have to separate two populations by a line in a scatterplot:

[image: Dot plot]

I would like find a threshold that separates the two populations. In @Waynes words, I would like to cluster the points into two categories, then calculate the line which best separates them. What is the easiest way to accomplish this in `R`? I've tried the Otsu algorithm on the raw data, but I don't know if this one is robust enough for other datasets.

**Edit:** I don't know which dot belongs to which population. The data is not multivariate, I only have an X and a Y value, as seen in the dotplot.

Comment: Do you know which dots belong to which population? (Ie, is this cluster analysis?) Are you wondering how to *get* the line, or how to *plot* a line that you already have?

Comment: No, I don't know which dot belongs to which population. The data is not multivariate, I only have an X and a Y value, as seen in the dotplot. I want to get the line.

Comment: So you're asking how to cluster the points into two categories, then calculate the line which best separates them?

Comment: Do you care if the line is straight, or can it be curved so long as it maximally differentiates the clusters? (I don't know if this will be important, I'm just asking out of thoroughness.)

Comment: @Wayne Exactly.

Comment: @gung For the sake of easiness it should be straight. But if you have other approaches leading to a curved line, I'm also interested for future applications.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, you say "I only have an X and a Y value, as seen in the dotplot". Do you have the *actual* X & Y values (eg, in a matrix), or do you only have the plot?

Comment: @gung I have the actual values.

Comment: In that particular case I'd take a kde on the y's (with not too large a bandwidth) and draw a horizontal line where that was a minimum, but to assert that is separating two populations requires a lot of assumptions I see no justification for so far.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a much simpler solution to this problem but something that will work is to first use K-means with two clusters. Once you know the class membership of each point, fit an SVM.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the previous answer, K-means is easy and effective. However, the K-means algorithm just lets you find structure in the data. I would not use the results as labels to train a supervised learning algorithm, like an SVM. Labels like the ones used for training imply a stronger claim to categorical knowledge than simple structural patterns.